# Python: NLTK: return dictionary - only returns 1 value

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

Sorry to dump a whole block of code (below) here. I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but unfortunately I have no idea.

For my thesis I have to classify tweets as neutral (0), negative (-1) or positive (1). I'm trying this by using NLTK. Goal is that the code returns a dictionary in the form 'tweetA,0','tweetB,-1'... At the moment, if I enter more than one tweet as an input, I only get the result (i.e. -1/0/1) for the first tweet back.

For example, if I put 'I love oranges','I hate tomatoes' as in input, I only get '1' as a return and not '1','-1'.

If anyone would be able to help me out, I'd be really grateful!

The code I have up until now:

```
import re, math, collections, itertools
import nltk
import nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist  
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.porter import *
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords = True)
pos_tweets = ['I love bananas','I like pears','I eat oranges']
neg_tweets = ['I hate lettuce','I do not like tomatoes','I hate apples']
neutral_tweets = ['I buy chicken','I am boiling eggs','I am chopping vegetables']

def uni(doc):
    x = []
    y = []
    for tweet in doc:
        x.append(word_tokenize(tweet))
    for element in x:
        for word in element:
            if len(word)>2:
                word = word.lower()
                word = stemmer.stem(word)
                y.append(word)
    return y

def word_feats_uni(doc):
     return dict([(word, True) for word in uni(doc)])

def tokenizer_ngrams(document):
    all_tokens = []
    filtered_tokens = []
    for (sentence) in document:
        all_tokens.append(word_tokenize(sentence))
    return all_tokens

def get_bi (document):
    x = tokenizer_ngrams(document)
    c = []
    for sentence in x:
        c.extend([bigram for bigram in nltk.bigrams(sentence)])
    return c

def get_tri(document):
    x = tokenizer_ngrams(document)
    c = []
    for sentence in x:
        c.extend([bigram for bigram in nltk.bigrams(sentence)])
    return c


def word_feats_bi(doc): 
    return dict([(word, True) for word in get_bi(doc)])

def word_feats_tri(doc):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in get_tri(doc)])

def word_feats_test(doc):
    feats_test = {}
i = 0
for tweet in doc:
    feats_test.update(word_feats_uni(tweet))
    feats_test.update(word_feats_bi(tweet))
    feats_test.update(word_feats_tri(tweet))
return feats_test


pos_feats = [(word_feats_uni(pos_tweets),'1')] + [(word_feats_bi(pos_tweets),'1')] + [(word_feats_tri(pos_tweets),'1')]

neg_feats = [(word_feats_uni(neg_tweets),'-1')] + [(word_feats_bi(neg_tweets),'-1')] + [(word_feats_tri(neg_tweets),'-1')]

neutral_feats = [(word_feats_uni(neutral_tweets),'0')] + [(word_feats_bi(neutral_tweets),'0')] + [(word_feats_tri(neutral_tweets),'0')]

trainfeats = pos_feats + neg_feats + neutral_feats
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print (classifier.classify(word_feats_test(['I love oranges'])))
```

Comment: last code line: you don't actually classify more than one tweet. how would it look like, if you submit more than one? would `classifier.classify_many()`  solve your problem?

Comment: @charbugs I solved the problem by adapting the logic of the code. Now I'm storing each tweet and its sentiment automatically in a list. So the classification function is called for each tweet separately.